# A pre-built extendable web application for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am wondering if there is a standard pre-built web application for Rails which has all the basic functionalities like user login, user profiles, profile image uploader, comments, search, maybe payments and a set of other usual web application features all bundled and ready to use and extend.

I like how Twitter bootstrap comes with a set of pre-built interface functionalities and styles, which you can start using and modify later. I am looking for something similar that can allow me to quickly set up a working application and go from there.

Does such a framework exist?

Comment: Check out [RailsApps](https://github.com/RailsApps). I've never used these myself, so I can't really offer advice on them. Several include tutorials and one is based on Devise (user authentication) and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

There [are](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber) [numerous](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan)  [examples](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap) [out](https://github.com/foxycoder/rails_template) [there](https://github.com/hugodias/railStrap).

However, there are two things you should really do:

1. Read the license to make sure you can use it they way you are thinking of using it.
2. Ensure you understand the design decisions and choices the original authors made. You will end up in a world of maintenance pain if you just copy cargo-cult style without understanding the tradeoffs others have made with their design decisions.

Any one of the links listed has enough to get you started. They may not have all of the features you listed but together they probably have all of your bases covered. You will have to put in some effort to get all those features working together though.

Answer (score 2):

The [RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.com/) project is great because they all have tutorials that walk through the basic setup.  They are also all built using the [Rails Composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/) tool, which lets you pick and choose certain options for your app.